# Two way assertion

Tags: java, testing, automation, assert

I am doing web automation testing, for example lets say I have two very basic scenarios:

> Test a) step 1: add record to the database step 
>   2: check if website
>   displayed record properly
>
> Test b) step 1: edit record on the website step
>   2: check if record
>   were properly saved in database

By record, let say it was simple text field with some "value"

So for first scenario, I would use Assert equal:

```
private void check1()
{
    Assert.assertEquals(valueFromDB, valueOnWebsite)
    //many more assertions for more values here        
}
```

but, for second scenario, it would be:

```
private void check2()
{
    Assert.assertEquals(valueOnWebsite, valueFromDB)
    //many more assertions for more values here        
}
```

So basically they both do the same, but are inverted, in order to throw correct error log if assertion was incorrect, now how to make it in single method, that could work for both cases, BUT would display correct assertion log if values were not equal?

Comment: You are already using a single method - `Assert.assertEquals`

Comment: but with inverted parameters, in order to get correct assertion log in case two values were no equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [overload which receives a message](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object))

```
String message = String.format("valueFromDB value: %s, valueOnWebsite value: %s", valueFromDB, valueOnWebsite);
Assert.assertEquals(message, valueFromDB, valueOnWebsite);
```

If you want to override the built in message you need to do your own implementation

```
if (!valueFromDB.equals(valueOnWebsite)) {
  throw new AssertionFailedError(String.format("valueFromDB value: %s, valueOnWebsite value: %s", valueFromDB, valueOnWebsite));
}
```

Comment: I tried to do that, however it still adds comparison of assertion: (expected: but was: ) which is misleading 

 org.junit.ComparisonFailure: Website values did not match values in the Database! expected:<[SADSAD]> but was:<[0294a4d7-5]>

Comment: I know I could rather make a boolean where is compare if values are equal, and if they are not, I could make Assert.fail(myMessage) but was wondering about different approaches

Comment: @MateuszMysliwiec Updated my answer.

Comment: Question if I may ask, method you provided (own implementation to override built in method) seems logical, however it does not seem to work, it prints:

 valueFromDB value: {0}, valueOnWebsite value: {1}

and it does not replace values with parameters, also intelii idea warns about "to many arguments for format string" thanks